# Github local cached ip address is different then expected remote ip address

Tags: networking, mac, dns, git, github

I cannot do a "Git pull" request without getting an error for public key (see below).

> git pull
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Running the check for configuration settings ( ' ssh -vT git@github.com  ' ),  this is what I get:

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/snowmac/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/snowmac/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowmac/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowmac/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/snowmac/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/snowmac/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/snowmac/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/snowmac/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The key piece I notice is this:

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
```

Which according to Git hub (https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) should be:

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
```

Which I think is my problem, but I've tried flushing DNS, changing DNS servers all to no effect on getting the ip address changed. The Git Hub article offers no solutions if the ip addresses are incorrect other then to check the spelling.

Any ideas on how I can fix my problem?

(Edit) -- SSH Keys used to work a few weeks ago. it has been a while since I last used git on this machine.

Comment: Regarding what IP address github.com is supposed to have, did you read [this recent announcement](https://github.com/blog/1457-upcoming-ip-address-changes)?

Comment: So it's not a ip address issue?

Comment: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key. That tells you the machine you are reaching is recognized as one in the known_hosts file. The error you are getting tells you github doesn't have a public key matching your private key. Why not generate a new key pair and install the public key on github?